# Google Analytics : What does E-Commerce report look like?

Tags: google-analytics, e-commerce, tracking

I have integrated the sample code as provided in [here](http://code.google.com/apis/analytics/docs/tracking/gaTrackingEcommerce.html#Example) to know how the additional data will be recorded in the analytics server.Based on which i could decide on how the parameters need to be sent across and how it could be viewed.

- I have made the profile as "E-Commerce Website:Yes"
- Created a custom report - e-COMMERCE with "Transactions" as metrics and "Products" as Dimensions.Hoping these will be sent across through the sample code.
- I have integrated the tracking code a couple of days before and is definitely more than 48 hrs.What additional things should i do to view the report?.If anyone could sent me a screen grab of the how report would look like and what additional things should i do to view similar reports?.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should edit your profile and enable Ecommerce reporting. Once you do so, you'll see a new report tab with plenty of Ecommerce relate report.s there's no need to create custom reports of something as simple as that.

Once you enable the Ecommerce reporting in your profile editing page you should wait yet another 24 hours.

Here's where it should be enabled/

[image]

Once you've done it the Ecommerce reports will show up like this:

[image]